# Menu item not working

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I am doing menu item. But i am not able to view the menu item in the screen. Can anybody tell me what is getting wrong or what other need to be added to get the code working. I have got totally stuck.

```
          package com.example.androiddemo;

          import android.app.Activity;
          import android.os.Bundle;
          import android.view.Menu;
          import android.view.MenuInflater;

           public class MenuItem extends Activity {

     @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.menu.menupage);
      }

    public boolean  onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menupage, menu);
            return true;
       }
        }
```

xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:icon="@drawable/images"
        android:title="About"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      />
   <item
        android:id="@+id/setting"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="App Setting"
        />
   </menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have to set your activity's xml file.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main); // Your activity's xml file.
      }

public boolean  onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menupage, menu); // Here you are setting the menu whatever options you want.
            return true;
       }
        }
```

After running this, just press on menu, It should show your options. If not post back.